# Regarding dataUrl in Struts2 jQuery Grid editoptions

Tags: jquery, struts2, grid

I need to implement a cascading select for listing country and state
in the grid. I have implemented it as shown below

```
    <sjg:gridColumn
            name="country.countryName"
            index="countryCode"
            title="Country Name"
            width="200"
            sortable="true"
            editable="true"
            search="true"
            surl="%{selectcountrysurl}"
            searchoptions="{sopt:['eq','ne'], dataUrl : '%{selectcountryurl}'}"
            searchtype="select"
            edittype="select"
            editoptions="{ dataUrl : '%{selectcountryurl}' ,
                                       dataEvents: [
                                       {  type: 'change',
                                          fn: function(value) {

                                    var params = 'selectedCountry='+this.value;
                                    $.get('get-state-list.action?'+params, function(data) {
                                            var stateDropDown = document.getElementById('stateName');
                                            stateDropDown.innerHTML = data;
                                    });

                             }
                          }
                      ]     }"
    />

    <sjg:gridColumn
            name="stateName"
            index="stateName"
            title="State Name"
            width="200"
            sortable="true"
            editable="true"
            search="true"
            surl="%{selectstateurl}"
            searchoptions="{sopt:['eq','ne'], dataUrl : '%{selectstateurl}'}"
            searchtype="select"
            edittype="select"
            id="stateSelect"
            editoptions="{ dataUrl : '%{selectstateurl}' }"
    />
```

With these settings, I could populate the state select box
corresponding to the selected country. But upon editing a row using
form edit, I could see that the state select box is populated with
already existing list as there is no call being made to the dataUrl. I
could see that the AJAX request to dataUrl is called only once when
the element is created. Is there anyway I can make this possible?

regards,
Arun

Comment: Can anybody help me on this issue please?

Comment: if u had a solution about the same,can u please share with me.